# REST setup in routes.php is not working when having two words controller names

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, routes, inflector

We are using CakePHP 3.10.*, friendsofcake/crud ^5.0 and friendsofcake/crud-json-api ^0.4.0. Lately we've been having trouble getting requests to the FirmantesExternosController to be handled according to REST conventions. Where, when sending a POST request, cakephp is expected to execute the "add" action of the controller. But instead, it executes the "index" action.

Here is our router scope inside routes.php

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

$routes->setExtensions(['json','xml']);
...(other resources)...
$routes->resources('Firmantes');
$routes->resources('FirmantesExternos');

$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
$routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);

$routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);

});
```

We also have in bootstrap.php

```
Inflector::rules('irregular', [
  ...(other inflections)...
  'firmante' => 'firmantes',
  'firmanteexterno' => 'firmantesexternos',
]);
```

And inside AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {

use \Crud\Controller\ControllerTrait;

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');

    $this->loadComponent('Crud.Crud', [
      'actions' => [
        'index' => [
            'className' => 'Crud.Index',
            'relatedModels' => true
        ],
        'view' => [
            'className' => 'Crud.View',
            'relatedModels' => true
        ],
        'add' => [
            'className' => 'Crud.Add',
            'relatedModels' => false
        ],
        'edit' => [
            'className' => 'Crud.Edit',
            'relatedModels' => false
        ],
        'delete' => [
            'className' => 'Crud.Delete',
            'relatedModels' => false
        ]
      ],
      'listeners' => [
          'Crud.Api',
          'Crud.RelatedModels',
          'CrudJsonApi.JsonApi'
      ]
    ]);
}
}
```

The FirmantesExternosController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class FirmantesExternosController extends AppController
{

}
```

The FirmantesController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class FirmantesController extends AppController
{

}
```

We are using crud component application wide as seen in AppController. Having the FirmantesController working as intended with the REST conventions after puting $routes->resources('firmantes'); in routes.php. But we do the same with FirmantesExternosController and it doesn't work. What are we missing?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that it's executing the index action, and not redirecting to the index URL after executing the add action?

Comment: The first argument of `RouteBuilder::resources()` is the controller name, so, mind the case sensitivity! **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#url-inflection-for-resource-routes**

Comment: @ndm Thanks for the suggestion. We changed to $routes->resources('Firmantes'); and $routes->resources('FirmantesExternos'); but this doesn't work neither.

Comment: @GregSchmidt When we send the POST resquest with the data necesary for creation, the response is exactly the same as when we sent a GET request. Seeing this in developer tools of chrome ---> Network menu. It responses only with the index action resulting array. 100% sure.

Comment: Temporarily remove the fallback routes (which is possibly what you're hitting unless one of the other routes that aren't being shown is catching the request), then use `bin/cake routes` to figure what URLs exactly are connected to which routes (note that in the CakePHP version that you're using they are not being shown in the order in which they would match), and check whether your request uses the correct path accordingly.

Comment: @ndm Thanks a lot. This solved the problem. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

THANKS A LOT! To all comments and suggestions.

I solved the problem doing the following:

1. Make sure to use "case sensitive controller names" in the $routes->resources('...'); lines. In this case $routes->resources('FirmantesExternos'); is the correct format.
2. In the console inside de cakephp project, run bin/cake routes to figure the route format that cakephp uses. And then make sure to use these in your requests to the api.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).